# Failed to clean when building wxwidgets using MinGW

Tags: c++, user-interface, mingw, wxwidgets

I have a problem when cleaning wxwidget using MinGW. The last error is like this :

```
make (e=2):system cannot find the file specified.
mingw32-make : *** [clean] error 2
```

and it seems like all of the errors are the same as the one I posted above, and that errors can be seen from the start of cleaning process (after typing mingw32 clean instruction).

Do you know how to solve this?

I have already followed every step mentioned in wxwidgets wiki and any other wiki that explain the way to install this. Of course I didn't install MSYS or anything mentioned in the wiki, just minGW only (and Code::Blocks, but both of them are installed separately).

BTW, I am using the latest stable minGW (3.8x) and the version of the wxwidgets I am getting problem with is 2.9.4.

Any help would be appreciated. sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Try my other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929310/mingw32-make-tries-to-create-subfolder-lib-an-illegal-name).