# mingw32-make fails to start

Tags: windows, dll, mingw

Whenever I try to run mingw32-make from cmd, I get this dialog:

[image: mingw32-make.exe - Application Error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.]

I've tried reinstalling mingw32-make (both the same and a previous version), but the problem persists. This error occurs regardless of any arguments or input given to mingw32-make, and regardless of whether there is a Makefile in the current directory.

I looked up the error, and it seems like it's a problem with the DLLs that mingw32-make depends on. I tried running Dependency Walker on mingw32-make.exe, and it looks like pretty much all of the DLLs it depends on (~140 seperate files) are 64-bit, while the application itself is 32-bit.

Is this an error in the MinGW installer? And is there an easy way to solve it, short of providing 32-bit versions for all of the DLLs it depends on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).
>   Click OK to close the application.

when running an application, then you should recall that `0xC000007B` is the code of `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`, which is a good evidence that 64-bit application is trying to load 32-bit DLLs or vice versa. You definitely have your `PATH` environment variable polluted with some other MinGW, for example, or god knows what else. Just clean things up and make it simple, you'll find the cause.

Further recommendations:

1. **[Why to prefer `make` (from MSYS) instead of `mingw32-make`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929310/mingw32-make-tries-to-create-subfolder-lib-an-illegal-name/15933528#15933528)**.
   You can download a bit dated, but latest stable MSYS **[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/)**. New
   version is under active development.
2. Use **[MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)** instead of **[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)**. You can download it
   **[here](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds)**. It already offers the bleeding-edge MinGW-w64 based on
   GCC 4.8.1. What's more it offers all the possible variations:

   - 64-bit targets;
   - 32-bit targets;
   - Win32 threads;
   - POSIX threads;
   - SEH exceptions;
   - DWARF exceptions;
   - SJLJ exceptions.

Comment: I have no desire to install MSYS just so that I can run `make`. But I'll take a look at MinGW-w64.

Comment: MSYS contains not only `make`. It has lots of useful Unix utilities which are essential to build certain 3rd party libraries. Furthermore it contains `bash` as well. All of these distributions are native and drop-in, i.e. require no installation, just unarchive, add to `PATH` and you are good to go. No actions behind your back which then cause what you have to deal now with.

Comment: I don't think there were "actions behind my back"; I think MinGW may have just made certain assumptions it should not have when installing. I'd rather avoid installing something as extensive as MSYS until I come to a point where I will actually need it; for now I just need a functioning GNU make replica.

Comment: The point is that `mingw32-make` is non-functional GNU Make, and it's admitted by MinGW developers themselves. It is strongly discouraged to use it. Anyway, you were warned, now it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

What is your processor architecture 64 bits or 32bits?

I had a smilar issue and I fix it by uninstalling Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable and downloading
and installing the [most current version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)

Comment: My processor is x86-64. I have the Visual Studio 2013 Preview installed, so I assume I'm getting my Visual C++ runtime libraries from that.